# How to use controllers and views in another project in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

If I have set up a project with lots of controllers and views, how could I use them  in another project in ASP.NET Core? I tried refering the project but when I use the views in previous project it just return NOT FOUND.

Answer (score 0):

While it is reasonable to create your own `ControllerFactory`, I found it more convenient to define all my Controllers in each project, but derive them from Controllers in my Shared project:

```
namespace MyProject1.Controllers
{
   public class MyController : MySharedProject.Controllers.MyController
   {
      // nothing much to do here...
   }
}

namespace MySharedProject.Controllers
{
   public abstract class MyController :  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
   {
      // all (or most) of my controller logic here...
   }
}
```

This has the added benefit that you have a place to put your Controller logic that differs from project to project. Also, it is easier for other developers to quickly find your Controller logic because the Controllers exist in the standard place.

Regarding whether this is advisable, I think it absolutely is. I've created some common Account Management logic that I want to share between projects that otherwise have very different business logic. So I'm sharing my Account and Admin Controllers, but the other Controllers are specific to their respective projects.